# why centre and acronym tags are removed in html5 since both tags are working fine?

Tags: html, css, tags

we can't use the centre and acronym tags anymore since they are removed in new version of html 5.Instead we have to use alignment equals to centre and abbreviation tag.

I try to use the both tags in html5 but they are not working anymore , instead the code is not executing .generally it was easy to use the centre and many more tags are there which are old and easy to use but they are gone now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<centre> 
    <p>hello this is samten here , i am framing question for stack overflow</p>
</centre>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`center` superseded by CSS in 1996.

`acronym` was never well supported (I'm talking semantics here, not the ability have to some default styling in the browser CSS) and often conflated with `abbr`. HTML 5 made that official and explicitly states you should use `abbr` instead of `acronym`.